# URL expander library for Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to write my first Android app in Kotlin, and one thing I'd like for my program to do is expand a shortened URL (t.co or goo.gl) into a full URL. Ideally I'd find a library that accomplishes this, but I can't find a good one for Java or Kotlin, so I'm trying to use some Java code that I've found online which has been converted to Kotlin by Android Studio. The code is below:

```
fun expandUrl(shortenedUrl: String?): String {
    val url = URL(shortenedUrl)
    // open connection
    val httpURLConnection = url.openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY) as HttpURLConnection

    // stop following browser redirect
    httpURLConnection.instanceFollowRedirects = false

    // extract location header containing the actual destination URL
    val expandedURL = httpURLConnection.getHeaderField("Location")
    httpURLConnection.disconnect()

    return expandedURL
}
```

This looks reasonable to me and compiles fine, but when I actually call it in a program --

```
val test = expandUrl("some t.co URL that I can't write in stack overflow as it's not allowed")
```

-- it seems that my 'expandedURL' is null, which crashes the program. As I didn't write the original code, I'm not sure how to debug it. Is there an actual library function I can use from somewhere, or anything obviously wrong with the expand URL code or how I'm calling it?

I have spent a few hours looking for the former and troubleshooting the latter, but I don't seem to be making much progress so I thought I would ask here. I'm probably being a massive idiot, so apologies if that's the case!

Comment: If you've spent a few hours on this, then by now you should know the full HTTP response to that request you make, i.e. the response where the code is blindly assuming you get a 3xx redirect, including actual response code and headers. If you want help, you need to show us that response in the question.

Comment: The fact that `expandedURL` is null would indicated that the response is not a 3xx redirect. It is probably an HTML page with a [meta refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh), or some JavaScript doing a refresh. Only by actually looking at the response will you learn what is going do, so please do *complete your research* into the response.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - I'm now doing different stuff based on the response code which has solved my issue.